# How to install every package in base Conda env from mambaforge?

Tags: anaconda, conda-forge, mamba, mini-forge

I just installed [mambaforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#mambaforge) on Windows 10, I don't have Anaconda installed yet as suggested in [mamba docs](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html). What I want to do achieve is to have the same packages installed you get when you install Anaconda from scracth.

Is there a way to retrieve the list of packages installed in **Anaconda** and install them using **mamba**? Or do I have to install Anaconda before installing Mamba? My goal is to have a basic Anaconda environment for testing purposes.

I tried: `mamba create -n fullanaconda anaconda` but I get: "nothing provides requested anaconda" from mamba. ([source](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7239#issuecomment-866772959))

It feels like I'm missing something important, any help would be appreciated.

`mamba info` returns:

```
    active environment : base
    active env location : C:\Users\uuu\AppData\Local\mambaforge
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\uuu\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\uuu\AppData\Local\mambaforge\.condarc
          conda version : 4.10.3
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.9.7.final.0
       virtual packages : __win=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : C:\Users\uuu\AppData\Local\mambaforge  (writable)
      conda av data dir : C:\Users\uuu\AppData\Local\mambaforge\etc\conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\uuu\AppData\Local\mambaforge\pkgs
                          C:\Users\uuu\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\uuu\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\uuu\AppData\Local\mambaforge\envs
                          C:\Users\uuu\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\uuu\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.10.3 requests/2.26.0 CPython/3.9.7 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.18363
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `anaconda` meta-package is only available from the `anaconda` channel, so it should work with

```
mamba create -n fullanaconda -c anaconda anaconda
```

Comment: Worked smoothly, thx!

Answer (score 1):

In my case I also needed to specify the Python version, other way I ended up with default (2.7), so I added:

`mamba create -n fullanaconda -c anaconda anaconda python=3.8`